# Correct method to submit complex data from EditorTemplates in MVC5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on my UserProfile editor and I'm using EditorTemplates for this, but I can't figure out the right way to submit data for complex objects using this method. I don't know if I have the right views or not, and how to roll up the complex object from all the partial views. To simplify, I will pare this down a bit, but my UserProfile has many sub-objects representing user preferences.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
    [UserProfileId]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NickName]          VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [ThumbnailImageId]  INT           NULL,
);
```

In my entities, I have navigation objects which point to the ThumbnailImage object, so in my EditorTemplate (for UserProfile) I can do this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NickName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NickName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ThumbnailImage, "ThumbnailImage", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ThumbnailImage, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Note that the second EditorFor is the ThumbnailImage object, not the ID. I have an EditorTemplate for that object, but I'm not sure which is the best way to code it up. I know how to do these, I'm just looking for which way to pick. If there is a "best practice" for this, please let me know.

**Option 1 - "Manually" roll up the top-level object in the UserProfile view.** For this option I would have an Ajax call in the UserProfile view, which submits the entire object, including the ThumbnailImageId which it would grab from the ThumbnailImage editor with JQuery using a prefix for the HTML element IDs. So, my submit button would live in the UserProfile EditorTemplate, and its action would look like this... (except the URL and element IDs would be generated)

```
var NickName = $('#MyNickNameId').val();
var ThumbnailImageId = $('#ImageEditorId').val();
$.ajax({
     url: '/Account/UserProfile',
     contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
     data: {
        UserProfileId: idVal, 
        NickName: NickName,
        ThumbnailImageId: ThumbnailImageId 
     }
 });
```

**Option 2 - Edit the sub-objects immediately** and don't submit them in the top-level view. In this option, my ThumbnailImage editor would update the database immediately using Ajax, by saving the image data itself, and then updating the parent object with the ID (if it changed). That way, when the user submits the top-level UserProfile editor, it would only submit the NickName, and any updates to the sub-objects will have already been completed. I like this option for smooth UI reasons, but I could make option 1 appear smooth to the user as well.

**Option 3 - Do away with the EditorTemplates for the sub-objects (ThumbnailImage) and edit them in the parent (UserProfile) view** - this means I will have repetitive code in views though, because other things will have ThumbnailImage objects, not just the user profile. Having the entire object in one view is a little simpler, but I don't really see any advantage in this (but, it's what we do at work, where we don't use model binding)

How do I figure out which option to go with, or is there a better option I'm not considering?

Currently I'm doing option 1. It works but it's a lot of code and not very re-usable.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your setup works neither understand C# stuff. But here is a standard practice made popular by Erlang actors currently in use by Object Oriented Design, Akka framework of Scala, multiple components of Ember.js etc.

Imagine a data centric tree. There is a root node. Each node has children and one parent.

Now imagine a tree of Objects. There is a root object called supervisor. Each node has children called workers and one parent which is called its supervisor. Each node supervises all of its children.

Supervision is defined as making sure supervised *actor* or in more general terms *object* is in an acceptable state. Can get requests, process them and reply back. For example on exception, a supervisor may choose to reinitialize supervised actor.

In a such system root gets the most abstract message, say getCredentials, and is in charge of building workers, splitting the task and keep track of local state.

Naturally root creates a form. Form being a child of root creates two actors in charge of handling `<input>` tags and one in charge of *sending* submit.

When submit actor tells its parent, form, that it should submit. Form asks each input for their value, builds a dict/hash out of it and replies to root with that data.

Now root is in charge of sending this data up to server. This way logic, data, state and behaviour stays in most local place possible.